# How many native speakers are members of Russian Language site?

Tags: discussion

Many answers on our site start from "As a native speaker I want to say that..." or "Native speaker here!". It looks though that many of the site members ARE the native speakers.

I doubt that anyone here knows exactly how many native speakers are here (but if I wrong - I would be glad to have your answer below).

So, to find out how many native speakers we have I decided to create a poll here.
Vote below for "I am a native speaker" if you are and "I am not a native speaker" if you are not.

Note that this is a community wiki post, so the post is not for the reputation - just for fun!

Comment: sorry, but it looks like this question is not a question and, therefore, most likely to be closed.

Comment: @shabunc Edited the post to be a question.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I am native Russian speaker!

Answer (score 1):

No, I am not a native speaker :(